# rc-tooltip flickering when tooltip is too close to window's edge

Tags: reactjs, tooltip

I'm noticing an issue with the rc-tooltip package that when the tooltip appears too close to the edge of the window, the tooltip flickers and can't seem to make up it's mind on where to place itself. It seems to happen when the tooltip's position is set to top/bottom and there is not enough left/right space to show the content of the tooltip. This happens on Chrome & Safari (not FF) and seems to even be an issue with their demo as well.

Has anyone encountered this issue? If so how did you get around it. I'm using the latest version of rc-tooltip. Is there an earlier version that doesn't have this issue? I've included a screen recording of the issue directly from the rc-tooltip demo.

https://react-component.github.io/tooltip/demo/arrow-content

[screen recording](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1CQH.gif)

The expected behaviour is to either have the tooltip show on the top/bottom as specified in the placement prop.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Seems this issue happens when a `width` is not specified on the overlay component via the `overlayClassName` prop. `width: max-content` seemed to fix the issue